# Knockout - How can I convert dynamically populated checkbox to radio button (yes/no)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, radio-button

I have a checkbox that is dynamically populates an array of objects but I now need convert it to radio buttons to now allow the user to select either Yes or No (instead of one checkbox)

```
<!--
From (checkboxes):
   [] Customer 1
   [] Customer 2

To (radio button Yes/No options):

  Customer 1 (customer code)
  [] Yes
  [] No
-->
```

I have a fiddle of my working checkbox and attempts(not successful yet) to convert them to of radio buttons - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lily30/w75px6r2/1/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=w75px6r2)

As per the fiddle, ultimately I need to POST back the array of selected customers {cusotmerType,checkedvalue}

Any advise is appreciated, to help me head to the right direction.
Many thanks

```js
function Customer(type,checked)
{
  var self = this;
  
  self.CustomerType = ko.observable(type); 
  self.IsChecked = ko.observable(checked || false);
}

function VM()
{
  var self = this;
  
  //dynamically populated - this is for testing puposes
  self.AllCustomers = ko.observableArray([
    { 
      code: "001",
      name:'Customer 1'
    },
    { 
      code: "002",
      name:'Customer 2'
    },
    { 
      code: "003",
      name:'Customer 3'
    },
  ]);
  
 self.selectedCustomers = ko.observableArray([]);
 self.Customer = ko.observableArray([]); //I need to POST this back- all selected customers
  
//return all customers that checked the box
self.selectedCustomers.subscribe(function() {
self.Customer.removeAll();
  ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.selectedCustomers(), function(item) {
      self.Customer.push(new Customer(item, true));
  });
});

}
ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- ko foreach: AllCustomers -->
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: $data.code, checked:$parent.selectedCustomers" /> 
   
  <span data-bind="text: $data.name"></span>
  <!-- /ko -->
  
  <h4>Selected customers</h4> 
  <div data-bind="foreach: Customer">
    <span data-bind="text: CustomerType"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: IsChecked"></span>
    <span>,</span>
  </div> 
  <br>
  <!-- I need to convert them into radio options 
  eg:
  Customer 1 (can be customer code)
  [] Yes
  [] No
  -->
  <strong>
  Not working yet..only one of the Yes/No can be selected among all cusotmers
  </strong><br><br>
   <!-- ko foreach: AllCustomers -->
   <span data-bind="text: $data.name"></span><br>
   <input type="radio" data-bind="value: $data.code,checked:$parent.selectedCustomers" />Yes
   <input type="radio" value="No" data-bind="checked:$parent.selectedCustomers" />No
   <br>
  <!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Done!

Comment: I'm still not quite getting it. :-) You want to completely remove the checkboxes, right? And just have the radio buttons? I ask because there seems to be some kind of interaction between the two above.

Comment: Yes, replace the checkboxes with radio button. The checkbox example just demonstrates how the radio button should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few issues with your code and most important are:

- radiobuttons work in groups which can be specified by `name` attribute
- knockout does not really work the same with observableArray (`selectedCustomers` in your case) on radiobuttons and checkboxes.

I've updated your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w75px6r2/7/
I really did not know what I could change and what not. So I left the input and output array the same. I only changed processing of data between those.
Based on that what you need is to figure out best solution.

In first part I only added another array prepared for view which just extends your original items with `isSelected` observable.

Then I am just binding it in the view. You should see now that checkboxes and radiobuttons should work both in the same view.

```js
function Customer(type, name, checked) {
  var self = this;

  self.CustomerType = ko.observable(type);
  self.Name = ko.observable(name);
  self.IsChecked = ko.observable(checked || false);
}

function VM() {
  var self = this;

  //dynamically populated - this is for testing purpose
  self.AllCustomers = ko.observableArray([{
      code: "001",
      name: 'Customer 1'
    },
    {
      code: "002",
      name: 'Customer 2'
    },
    {
      code: "003",
      name: 'Customer 3'
    },
  ]);

  self.AllCustomersViewModel = ko.observableArray(
    self.AllCustomers().map(function(value) {
      value.isSelected = ko.observable(false);
      return value;
    }));

  self.selectedCustomers = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    var result = [];
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.AllCustomersViewModel(), function(item) {
      if (item.isSelected()) {
        result.push(item);
      }
    });
    return result;
  });
  self.Customer = ko.observableArray([]); //I need to POST this back- all selected customers

  //return all customers that checked the box
  self.selectedCustomers.subscribe(function() {
    self.Customer.removeAll();
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.selectedCustomers(), function(item) {
      self.Customer.push(new Customer(item.code, item.name, true));
    });
  });

}
ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<!-- ko foreach: AllCustomersViewModel -->
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isSelected" />

<span data-bind="text: name"></span>
<!-- /ko -->

<h4>Selected customers</h4>
<div data-bind="foreach: Customer">
  <span data-bind="text: CustomerType"></span>
  <span data-bind="text: IsChecked"></span>
  <span>,</span>
</div>
<br>

<!-- I need to convert them into radio options 
  eg:
  Customer 1
  [] Yes
  [] No
  -->
<strong>
  Not working yet..only one of the Yes/No can be selected among all customers
  </strong><br><br>
<!-- ko foreach: AllCustomersViewModel -->
<span data-bind="text: name"></span><br>
<input type="radio" data-bind="value: true, checked: isSelected, attr: {name: $index}" />Yes
<input type="radio" data-bind="value: false, checked: isSelected, attr: {name: $index}" />No
<br>
<!-- /ko -->
```